# Tornado Python as daemon

Tags: python, linux, nginx, tornado, daemon

I have my code written with tornado and I want to make it work pretty much like apache or nginx, that is

1. It must keep listening to the port even when I close the shell.
2. It must start automatically on system restart

I have tried nohup command to make it work even when I close the shell. It works. But I am wondering if there is a cleaner option available for the same?

Comment: Your question is already answered [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383741/python-daemonize

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nginx Tornado and Flask - What's a good start/stop script and keep-alive method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557450/nginx-tornado-and-flask-whats-a-good-start-stop-script-and-keep-alive-method)

Comment: Please check https://github.com/facebook/tornado/wiki/Deployment , the official documentation for best practices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taken from the official documentation [here](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/wiki/Deployment).

### Overview

Most Tornado apps are run as single processes. For production, this usually means a fairly straight-forward combination of external process management and proxying. Here are some gathered best practices/resources.

### Development

When [debug mode](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/overview.html#debug-mode-and-automatic-reloading) is enabled, templates are not cached and the app will automatically restart during development. This will fail if a Python syntax error occurs, however. (This can be worked around w/ some [additional code](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/python-tornado/OANxsGUP2IA/dOcUh0b8YmYJ) or by using [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) in development)

You might want to run your app from a terminal multiplexer like [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) for more flexibility in leaving things running and tracing fatal errors.

#### Instrumentation

### Production

Typically in production, multiple tornado app processes are run (at least one per core) with a frontend proxy.  Tornado developer bdarnell has a [tornado-production-skeleton](https://github.com/bdarnell/tornado-production-skeleton/) illustrating this using [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) (process management) and [nginx](http://nginx.org/) (proxying).

#### Process Management

Traditionally, Tornado apps are single-process and require an external process manager, however [HTTPServer can be run with multiple processes](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpserver.html#http-server). Additionally, there are a couple [additional helpers](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/process.html) for helping out with managing multiple processes.

Supervisor

- [Managing multiple Pylons apps with Supervisor](http://countergram.com/pylons-supervisor) - an excellent tutorial for getting started with Supervisor
- [Deploy tornado application](http://blog.thisisfeifan.com/2012/06/deploy-tornado-application.html) - short tutorial w/ Supervisor and nginx setup walkthrough
- [supervisord-example.conf](https://gist.github.com/802561) - this is an example cfg for running 4 tornado instances
- [Nginx Supervisod Module](http://nginxvslighttpd.com/2011/06/02/nginx-supervisord-module/) - this module allows nginx to start/stop backends on demand

Daemonizing

- [start-stop-daemon example](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/python-tornado/g6cBspIplMQ/4l7Sv_K6afIJ) - if you are running a standard Linux system this is an easy way to daemonize your Tornado app
- [Upstart example](https://gist.github.com/csytan/10597221) - Upstart is built into Ubuntu and can respawn crashed instances.

Tornado Multi-Process

As mentioned above, Tornado's [HTTPServer can be configured](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpserver.html#http-server) for both multiple processes on a single or multiple sockets.

#### Proxying

The official docs includes an [example for running nginx](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/stable/guide/running.html#running-behind-a-load-balancer) as a load balancing proxy and for serving static files.

#### Deployment

- [Deploying Python web (Tornado) applications to multiple servers](https://serverfault.com/questions/274154/deploying-python-web-tornado-applications-to-multiple-servers) - short discussion on using a Load Balancer for live migration w/o downtime
- [Rolling Deployment w/ Fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148443/is-there-a-way-to-conduct-rolling-deployment-in-fabric-files)
- [Python Deployment Anti-Patterns](http://hynek.me/articles/python-deployment-anti-patterns/)
- [buedafab](https://github.com/bueda/ops) - a nice collection of Fabric 
  deployment scripts w/ EC2

Comment: I am neither the asking-man nor the answer-man. But why this reply is down-rated.

Answer (score 4):

I am using Python 3 and supervisord is not support python3 currently.
My solution is native

create a new file as "my_tornado_app.service" on "/etc/systemd/system/"

and content

```
[Unit]
Description=MyTornadoApp1.0
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /var/vhosts/mytornado-app/app.py
User=www-data
Restart=on-failure
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable my_tornado_app.service.service
sudo systemctl start my_tornado_app.service.service
```

And working!

Answer (score 2):

In short: Use `supervisord` and/or `nginx`.

Check this link out: http://blog.thisisfeifan.com/2012/06/deploy-tornado-application.html