# how to host developed hybrid application?

Tags: ember.js, tornado, rethinkdb

I have developed android hybrid application using frontend ember.js and backend tornado web server and rethinkdb database. And I don't how to host it on online. Can you please show me how to host.Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use compose , follow this link
https://www.rethinkdb.com/blog/compose/
they are hosting now rethinkdb.. Ypu can also check their docs for API.

compose is formerly know as MongoHQ.

Comment: And where to host the python tornado web server bro.

Comment: You can host it using nginx. 
You can look for hosting company that offers nginx. I am not sure if others will agree, you can also look for VPS or dedicated hosting so you can install your own nginx..

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/running.html

Comment: Maybe you can get idea also here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841957/tornado-python-as-daemon